# PHP Soap client incomplete response

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I connect to a SOAP-service with PHP.

When I ask a function for a response I don't get all of the xml-tags in the response. But when I use SoapUI to connect to the same service with the same parameters, I get all of the response.

I have cleared /tmp folder on mye webservice, and I connect like this, without caching:

```
$this->client = new SoapClient( $wsdl, array( 'proxy_host' => $ip, 'proxy_port' => 8082, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE ) );
```

I'm assuming that it is something on my webserver that is working differently than SoapUI, does anyone know what this something could be??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15190155/soapui-vs-java-web-service-client hope this will help you

Comment: Yes it looks like it actually does! I ran a test in SoapUI, and it failed due to a missing letter in a schema. I guess the PHP-client picks up on that.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo in the webservice. SoapUI didn't react to it. PHP did.