# JSON response validation against JSON schema using groovy script

Tags: validation, groovy, soapui, json-schema-validator

I have a rest service which returns a json response. I need to validate response against my predefined json schema using groovy script. All the options I have found on the net describe validating json response using  groovy.json.JsonSlurper against some pre conditions not the schema. So I am kinda confused where to start from. But I roughly know that I need the following steps get done.

1. Define custom json schema
2. Importing some json validator library
3. And validate response against schema in groovy

I'd be highly grateful if anybody helps out on the steps 2 and 3.
For your notice, I am using Soap ui tool and here is my custom schema:

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/schema#",
"type":"array",
"items":{
"type": "string"
}
}
```

Comment: devgirl, check out the third answer at this link.. where xml is validated against the xsd.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317017/soapui-validate-response-against-xsd-schema-file should be similar

Comment: The question is about json schema not xml schema

Answer (score 0):

Loading libraries in Groovy depends on the tool. In SoapUI-5.6.0 the standard way is to put jar files in (from SoapUI base installation path):

- On Mac: `bin/ext`
- On Linux & Windows: `lib`

Validation differs depending on the library. For example with [groovy-json-schema](https://github.com/alexdeleon/groovy-json-schema):

```
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"an": "example"}')
use(JsonSchema) {
    json.schema = 'file://path/to/your/json/schema.json'
    json.conformsSchema()
}
```